# Code igniter Fetching Data to html page by page but getting all records at a time using jquery datatable plugin

Tags: codeigniter

i am using jquery datatable to show records in codeigniter. but i am getting all 20000 records at time. i want to get records from db page by page

my view file

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="ref_tbl">
    <thead>
    <th>Record Id</th>
    <th>User Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
         <?php
           $srno = 1;
          foreach ($companyd as $us):
           ?>
            <tr>
          <td><?php echo $srno++; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $us['comp_id']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

controller---

```
public function allusers() {
        $data['companyd'] = $this->admin_model->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_company limit 100");       
        $this->load->view('admin/companyview', $data);
    }
```

i am new at codeigniter. i tried to set limit. but i want pass page number to limit query. please anyone have know the how to solve this problem

Comment: for pagination data, you need to add `ajax datatable` kindly check ajax datatable and set your code according.

Comment: are you using jquery datatable.js plugin? so there is no need to add pagination there

Comment: in datatable.js plugin option is avalable for page per item: $('#ref_tbl').DataTable({"lengthMenu": [[20, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "All"]]});

Answer (score 0):

try this:

//controller

```
public function allusers() {
        $data['companyd'] = $this->admin_model->get_all_users();
        $this->load->view('admin/companyview', $data);
    }
```

//model

```
function get_all_users(){
return $this->db->get('tbl_company')->limit('100')->result_array();
}
```